# Animate constraints programmatically Swift 3

Tags: swift, animation

I have a view which I have set the position and size through constraints:

```
    oV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    oV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    oV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.widthAnchor, constant: -overlaySpacing).isActive = true
    oV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.heightAnchor, constant: -overlaySpacing).isActive = true
```

However, I want the oV (view) to start out as smaller than this and animate to the final size over the course of a second.

```
oV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
oV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
oV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.widthAnchor, constant: -2 * overlaySpacing).isActive = true
oV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.heightAnchor, constant: -2 * overlaySpacing).isActive = true
```

The initial constraints which I have written are the ones in which the constant is (-2 * overlaySpacing). The final constraints are where the width/height constant is just -overlaySpacing.

I have written everything programmatically so storyboard solutions won't help.

This is my current code to animate, however it just automatically appears as the final constraints:

let oV = NewOverlayView(viewController: mVC, frame: CGRect.zero)

```
    self.mapViewController.view.addSubview(oV)

    oV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    oV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    var widthConstraint = oV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.widthAnchor, constant: -2 * overlaySpacing)
    var heightConstraint = oV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.heightAnchor, constant: -2 * overlaySpacing)

    widthConstraint.isActive = true
    heightConstraint.isActive = true

    oV.layoutIfNeeded()

    widthConstraint.isActive = false
    heightConstraint.isActive = false

    widthConstraint = oV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.widthAnchor, constant: -overlaySpacing)
    heightConstraint = oV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.heightAnchor, constant: -overlaySpacing)

    widthConstraint.isActive = true
    heightConstraint.isActive = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { oV.layoutIfNeeded() }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A property observer with the [proper function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate) for animations can be a solution :

## **1.**

Set a variable in your controller with a "didSet" observer like this :

```
    var dynamicOverlaySpacing = 0 {
    didSet {
             //Remove previous constraints ?        
             oV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.widthAnchor, constant: -dynamicOverlaySpacing).isActive = true
             oV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.mapViewController.view.heightAnchor, constant: -dynamicOverlaySpacing).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

Ever time the value of **dynamicOverlaySpacing** is changed, the code in didSet closure will be executed.

## **2.**

Create an animation that will slowly change the value of **dynamicOverlaySpacing**

Something like this should work :

```
let delay = 2.0 //the delay you want for the animation
let firstOverlaySpacing = dynamicOverlaySpacing
oV.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
             dynamicOverlaySpacing = -2*firstOverlaySpacing

            }, completion: nil)
```

On options, I use curseEaseIn. You can see all the options available [here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions)

I didn't try the code, but it should work.